# The data in Next.js shows as array, different from the JSON object returned by the API

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js

I fetch data from Laravel API using `getServerSideProps()`:

This is how I fetch the data:

```
function Product({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>Hello</div>
  )

}
    
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/`, {
    method: 'GET',
  })
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Product
```

This is the output in the console:

[image: Different data array]

So it means in order to get the actual value for a product I'll need to extract it from `props` like so: `data.data[0].name` - is there a better way to do it? It looks too complicated and prone to errors. Can I get a non-nested array in the first place?

*Also, the API returns a different object, and not an array like shown in the picture above

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"some-product","price":"1250331.30","created_at":"2021-08-12T11:01:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-08-12T11:01:28.000000Z"},
    
{"id":2,"name":"some-other-product","price":"1141260.11","created_at":"2021-08-12T13:57:54.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-08-12T13:57:54.000000Z"}]}
```

Comment: Your code is invalid, you can't `return props` because there is no `props` variable. Maybe you made a typo?

Comment: `return {props: data}` and access it via `props.data` inside your component

Comment: @Danila from some reason it works. I guess because I return it from the export function and `props` is a special keyword in React? This is the actual console output of this code. And even if I do as the docs say like @Dupocas suggested, the data is still going to be nested, just 1 word less: `data.data[0].name`

Comment: It can't possibly work, I am pretty sure you have a typo and your actual code is different. React does not add any special keywords to javascript language.

Comment: @Danila, edited the code to the original code, but as you can see, it's still nested.

Comment: Yep, seems ok now. So what is the problem again? You don't want to have nested `data.data` field? Just do what @gladix said, destructure it inside the `getServerSideProps` function. Also, there is no nested array anywhere. You have an object called `data` with field called `data` and this field is just simple one dimension array, not nested.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I got confused about the nested array. I guess Next wraps the data array from the API with a data object from some reason instead of just displaying what was received from the API directly?

Comment: No, it does not, you are doing it. Your api returns object with `data` property, and then you return object with `data` property (which now contains api answer with `data` property) from `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the destructuring notation ?

```
 const { data } = await res.json()
```

Comment: That's an option. But then it's very confusing code for those who aren't fluent with destructurings. I can give it a try though, thank you!

Comment: I am not sure it will add some clarity to who can read your code, but you can also rename the property you are extracting if you want to, using the following notation (I learned it recently and it is quite usefull sometimes)
const { data: innerData  } = await res.json() 
return { props: { data: innerData  } }

Comment: Or rename it to something different when returning from `getServerSideProps ` like that `return { props: { products: data } }`